# React - Leave Promise catch scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

How do I leave promise catch scope when I call a function inside of .then ?

```
somePromise().then(result => this.setState({result})).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

In this case, if any error occurs after the state being set (e.g. in the render() method), the error will fall to this promise catch().

There is any way to prevent it ?

Comment: Do `.catch()` before `.then()`?

Comment: do you mean like this? `somePromise().then(result => this.setState({result}), e => console.log(e))` - the second argument to `.then` being "onRejected", used this way, it only "catches" any rejection on `somePromise()`

Comment: Both worked, thanks!